# Main windows freezes then button is clicked PyQt5

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I currently starting a project in Python 3 with PyQt5 as UI-Framework.
I had to run some tasks in the background when i click a button and all the other buttons have to stay responsible.
I have written a program to test this behavior and it doesn't work. Then I click the 'Get data' button my program freezes until the execution of run() function ends.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThreadPool, QRunnable
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QWidget

GREEN_STYLE = "QPushButton {background-color:rgb(0,200,0) ; " \
    " color: White; border-radius: 3px; height:70%; width:70%} " \
    "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(0,150,0) ; }"

RED_STYLE = "QPushButton {background-color:rgb(200,0,0) ;"\
    " color: White; border-radius: 3px; height:70%; width:70%} " \
    "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(150,0,0) ; }"

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Hello, world!'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.button_grid = QGridLayout()
        # self.button_grid.setSpacing(50)
        self.addButtons()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setLayout(self.button_grid)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        # self.showFullScreen()
        self.show()

    def event_mcs(self):
        threadCount = QThreadPool.globalInstance().maxThreadCount()
        print(threadCount)
        pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        th1 = DataThread('first', 'lotname')
        pool.start(th1)

    def addButtons(self):
        bttn_MCS = QPushButton('Get data')
        bttn_MCS.setStyleSheet(RED_STYLE)
        bttn_MCS.clicked.connect(self.event_mcs)
        self.button_grid.addWidget(bttn_MCS, 1, 2)
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                if(x == 1 and y == 2):
                    continue
                button = QPushButton('Hello')
                button.setStyleSheet(GREEN_STYLE)
                self.button_grid.addWidget(button, x, y)

class DataThread(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, name, lotName):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.lotName = lotName

    def run(self):
        for i in range(100000001):
            if i == 100000000:
                print('done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It seems like my code is missing something, but I can't figure out what :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you specify what OS are you using, and the versions of both Python and PyQt? (the PyQt version can be accessed from `QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR`)

Comment: I'm running it on Windows 10 with Python 3.9.5 and PyQt 5.15.2 installed using pip.